Sci-fi / futurism supplement from a UK newspaper in 1999/2000
To coincide with the new millennium in 2000, a UK newspaper (I believe it was The Sunday Times but I could be mistaken) published a five-part supplement containing speculative stories from the years 2000-2050, written in the form of short news snippets. This was either published in late 1999 or early 2000.
Each of the five parts covered a decade, so 2000-10, 2010-20, 2020-30 etc. They were short, approximately 10 pages each, and to my recollection each page covered stories from one year in the decade.
Some examples of stories included -

The first lab-grown human
The colonisation and mining of Mars, and the fight against crime there.
Humans being genetically engineered to increase intelligence

I remember reading this as a teenager around 1999/2000 and would love to read them again. Can anyone recall the name of this supplement and/or knows where I can read it online?

These supplements were called Chronicle of the Future and were published by The Sunday Times, in collaboration with the company that ran the Millennium Dome in London.
A (charmingly retro) online version is available here:
http://www.dome2000.com/chronicle/

That's exactly it, thank you! If you don't mind me asking, how did you find these? Or did you just remember them?

@ChrisTaylor - I remember they existed, and I knew that they were from the Sunday Times, as it was the paper my parents read. I Googled something like "sunday times future millennium supplements" and there was a old site with various millennium dome resources on the first page. I didn't think that would be it (had forgotten the link to the dome company), but I tried it anyway and it had a link to that archive

Nice, thanks. I tried various combinations of words in Google, but the key one I was missing was "Millennium"

"Chronicle of the Future is best viewed using IE v4 and above or Netscape v4 and above".  Yup, that's retro. :)
